# vim latex: disable quickfix

Tags: vim, latex

How can I disable latex's quickfix feature when editing tex files (having vimlatex installed). But I want to keep it for any other language…

Pretty sure this is just a small flag, didn't find it 'though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Note: I do not have vim-latex installed. I have just looked at likely parts of the plugin’s code.</sub>

What behavior do you want to avoid?

The documentation says that you can set `g:Tex_GotoError` to prevent automatically jumping to the first error after using `\ll` to compile.

```
let g:Tex_GotoError = 0
```

Also, the code indicates that you can inhibit the log file preview-mode window (below the quickfix window) by setting `Tex_ShowErrorContext`:

```
let g:Tex_ShowErrorContext = 0
```

I did not see an option for controlling whether the quickfix window itself is left open, however. You can close it manually with `:cclose` (which can be shortened to `:ccl`).

For both of the above variables, you can use a buffer-local (`b:…`) or window-local (`w:…`) instead of the global (`g:…`) to localize the effect if you do not want to change the behavior globally.

Comment: worked like a charm :-)